How to solve a polynomial made up of vector components for t
So I am trying to symbolically solve a polynomial equation in mathematica that is described with vectors:
cylindA = {ax, ay, az}
cylindB = {bx, by, bz}
rayR = {px + t*dx, py + t*dy, pz + t*dz}
distInt = Cross[(rayR - cylindA), (rayR - cylindB)]
Q = cylindB - cylindA
Solve[((distInt[[1]]*distInt[[1]] + distInt[[2]]*distInt[[2]] + 
        distInt[[3]]*distInt[[3]])/(Q[[1]]*Q[[1]] + Q[[2]]*Q[[2]] + 
        Q[[3]]*Q[[3]])) - r^2 == 0, t]

but it cannot symbolically put together the last equation to solve for t. Is there another way for this to be specified for it to solve?
The goal of this is to compute the intersection of Ray P+tD and a cylinder defined by Points A and B. The implicit eqn of a cylinder is ||Cross(P-A,P-B)||/||B-A|| = R. So my goal is to plug in the ray into the implicite eqn as point P and then solve for t in the resulting eqn to find the intersection point.
(I am learning mathematica for the first time and my mini project for learning is getting equations for raytracing surfaces, this one specifies a cylinder)

You want to solve for t but I don't see any t in your equations, unless you might mean tD is supposed to have t and D separate. You use K[0] which MMA thinks is a function K with an argument of 0 but you haven't defined a function K. You do Q[2]*Q[1] and people don't often multiply two vectors. Do you perhaps mean "dot product" instead, which is . in MMA.  MMA usually expects Solve[lhs==rhs,var] but you don't have any ==rhs. Can you perhaps edit your question to add a paragraph to describe your problem "in ordinary math terms and words" to help us understand?

Perhaps you are confusing single brackets [] for function application and double brackets [[]] for element extraction.

Also point #3 in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395 : Avoid subscripted symbols in your code. And point #4: Avoid symbol names that begin with a capital, especially names that are single capitals

Perhaps you mean Solve[((M . M)^2/(Q . Q)^2) == r^2, t]. If so, I think you need to spend some time learning the basics of the language.

@Bill thanks for the help I made some changes!

Element indices start at 1 in Mathematica. They start at 0 in C.

@MichaelE2 yes! thanks for the help. Does the . equate to the dot product?

After help from the comments this was the resulting solve query:
cylindA = {ax, ay, az}
cylindB = {bx, by, bz}
rayR = {px + t*dx, py + t*dy, pz + t*dz}
distInt = Cross[(rayR - cylindA), (rayR - cylindB)]
Q = cylindB - cylindA
FullSimplify[Solve[((distInt . distInt)/(Q . Q)) - r^2 == 0, t]]

the only thing next for me to figure out is how to simplfy the result back into vector operations like Dot Products and Cross Products :)

It is probably going to be difficult to put your result back into Dot and Cross products because Mathematica thinks every time that it sees something like the dot or cross of two vectors that it desperately wants to do that operation so it can show you the result. Depending on what you are trying to do, it might be possible to not do the Solve and maybe get it to give you a vector result, but Mathematica may fight you at every step of doing this. Perhaps if you can explain what you REALLY want to do and not what you think might be Mathematica code then maybe someone can suggest a way.

@Bill i did add a paragraph of what I am trying to do. I am writing a ray tracing shader of a ray against a cylinder and I need to find the t values where the ray intersects the cylinder. The goal of the shader is to express it in vector operations so that it can be done efficently with gpu simd code aka vector operations. But i needed an equation for the intersection first

I think your explanation was very helpful. Well done.
